# Sphinx: force subsection before section in a document

Tags: python-sphinx, markup, restructuredtext

I want to write a documentation page where I have something like:

```
Title
*****

Introductory text

Subsection with more details
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Details

Section 1
=========

Section 2
=========
```

Unfortunately, this only renders *Subsection with more details* as the main section, with all subsequent ones being the subsections. From my research, it seems to happen because Sphinx doesn't have a fixed hierarchy for headings and instead it just interprets
the document structure to decide on what the sections are, based on their succession (as seen at https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html).

I have also tried using upper markup to titles, to force section hierarchy, but that doesn't seem to work either.
Is there a not too invasive way of doing this? This page is for an open source project with lot of documentation pages already, not all following the same markup standards, and I'm afraid that if I tried to somehow define in our settings what each section/subsection marker should look like, we would have a lot of formatting headache ahead of us... (or I would, hehe)

```
=========
Section 1
=========
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can use `rubric`, https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#rubric or `topic`, https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#topic

Comment: Those options look interesting, thanks! For the moment I ended up with a workaround of sorts, but if that doesn't work out, or for the next time I have to do something like this, I'll try one of these. =]

Comment: @Jufajardini would you care to to share your workaround? Would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Aw, sorry for not mentioning _then_ what it was! Tbh I'm not sure but. I think I ended up reorganizing document contents/ sections in such a way that the hierarchy perceived by Sphinx would respect what I had in mind. Here's what the end result looks like https://github.com/OISF/suricata/commit/28b5f4a55557eb30fa71a908dec1bd8a0e5633fa
(I'm mad that I can't recall which sections were giving me a headache... )

Answer (score 2):

There is no "level" attribute in Docutils [`<section>`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#section) elements. Subsections are nested inside their parent sections and the section level is derived from the nesting level.

Depending on the actual needs, you may use several workarounds:

- Restructure the document to have a standard section layout.
- Use a [body element](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#body-elements) that provides for a title (topic, sidebar, rubric) for material outside of the main document outline (i.e. should not appear in a ToC).
- Use a sister-section level and style it with custom CSS.

Example:

```
Title
*****

Introductory text

.. rst-class:: details-section

Minor section with more details
===============================

Section 1
=========
...
```

and a custom CSS rule like `.details-section h2 {font-size: large}`.

Comment: Restructuring the document was my solution, but body elements sound good, I didn't know them, thanks!

CSS wouldn't be a good idea for us, I imagine, as we also use our docs to convert to pdf and I'm afraid this could mess up with that part.